# How to create cookie using selenium?

Tags: selenium-rc

I want to create a cookie using selenium.  I have seen a method which supports this like `selenium.createcookie(arg1,arg0)`, but I'm a bit confused about the arguments passed.  Can anyone please give me an example?

Answer (score 6):

createCookie ( nameValuePair,optionsString )
    Create a new cookie whose path and domain are same with those of current page under test, unless you specified a path for this cookie explicitly.

Arguments:

1. nameValuePair - name and value of
   the cookie in a format "name=value"
2. optionsString - options for the
   cookie. Currently supported options
   include 'path' and 'max_age'. the
   optionsString's format is
   "path=/path/, max_age=60". The order
   of options are irrelevant, the unit
   of the value of 'max_age' is second.

source: [Selenium reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html)

Comment: Can we give the cookie domain in any of the argument? Coz that cookie should get added to some xyz domain.Please help

Comment: I guess you can set the domain= attribute as one of the options in optionsString argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
createCookie ( nameValuePair,optionsString )
```

Create a new cookie whose path and domain are same with those of current page under test, unless you specified a path for this cookie explicitly.

```
Arguments:

nameValuePair - name and value of the cookie in a format "name=value"
optionsString - options for the cookie. Currently supported options include 'path' and 'max_age'. the optionsString's format is "path=/path/, max_age=60". The order of options are irrelevant, the unit of the value of 'max_age' is second.
```

Comment: http://www.cloudtesting.com/blog/2009/08/24/howto-cookie-manipulation-with-selenium-and-cloud-testing/

Answer (score 1):

Go on a site of your choice (that does create cookies) using firefox and go to Edit>Preferences>Privacy>Remove Individual Cookies. Click on one of the cookies. This will give you an idea of how to use the createCookie call. I switched the term of the option Domain the term by Host, which worked fine.